# -[UIBarButtonItem setTitlePositionAdjustment:forBarMetrics:] ignores vertical offset

Tags: ios, uikit, uinavigationbar, uibarbuttonitem

I have an application with some custom positioned bars, and as such I'd like to change the standard vertical alignment of the button text. I've tried setting

```
[buttonItem setTitlePositionAdjustment:UIOffsetMake(0, -22) forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault]
```

but nothing changes. Oddly, if I set a horizontal offset, the button moves just fine. It appears only vertical alignment changes are not being respected. Is this a bug on iOS 7? Am I misunderstanding something about the API? I see no documentation saying that the vertical alignment is ignored.

([example project showing the issue](http://cl.ly/3F2w100L0L05))

Comment: You may have better luck trying to create a UIBarButtonItem with a customView. Create a normal UIButton, and add that as the custom view and create the UIBarButtonItem with custom view.

Comment: I tried doing that using a `UIButton` with an origin of `(0, -22)`, but the bar also appears to ignore that, (which kinda makes sense since its repositioning the views anyways).

Comment: You need to adjust the UIButton's TitleEdgeInsets, not the origin of the UIButton itself. Example: `setTitleEdgeInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 8, 0, 0)];`

Comment: The issue with that is it sets the text outside the actual frame of the button, which un-alignes the hit bounds and visible bounds (see: http://cl.ly/image/0z1Y1N2h412U)

Comment: @axiixc I'm facing the same issue, did you manage to fix this?

Answer (score 4):

Unfortunately `setTitlePositionAdjustment:forBarMetrics:` doesn't appear to take effect. The best workaround I found was to use a UIButton instead, which can be done right in Interface Builder.

1. Add a `UIButton` to the `UIBarButtonItem` and set the font or image, size, etc.
2. In the Attributes Inspector, set the `UIButton`'s control alignment to right

[image: ib screenshot]

3. Hook the button back up to whatever actions you need